Best options for good quality and quick rendering of long animations
I have just completed a 50 second animation that uses a HDRI sky as well as various other lights. I am using the cycles render engine. I am not new to blender but do not have any experience rendering things. I have seen people pump out great looking animations, but I always wonder how they are able to do it without it taking weeks to render. I believe I am doing something wrong.
My animation does make use of the HDRI, it is a city at dusk but it switches to interior shots (which looks onto the outside street). Is there any alternative or optimisations I can make, or should I just start looking into render farms.
I can link my animation project if needed. Any suggestions regarding optimising will also be welcome. (Including materials)
Thanks

Hi I believe the linked post shoulbd broadly answer your question. If you have any more specific questions or particular concerns, please edit your post and rephrase it to focus on the particular aspect you are having difficulties with.
